# Python backtracking

Tags: recursive-backtracking

I have a basic problem in Python where I have to verify if my backtracking code found some solutions (I have to find all sublists of 1 to `n` numbers with property `|x[i] - x[i-1]| == m`). How do I check if there is some solution? I mean the potentially solutions I find, I just print them and not save them into memory. I have to print a proper message if there is no solutions.

Comment: Maybe dissociate computing from I/O operation (here, printing), by implementing a generator. Then you can check if you have at least a first value in your generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested in comment, you might want to dissociate computing from I/O printing, by creating a generator of your solutions of `|x[i] - x[i-1]| == m`

Let's assume you defined a generator for *yielding* your solutions:

```
def mysolutions(...):
    ....
    # Something with 'yield', or maybe not.
    ....
```

Here is a generator decorator that you can use to check if an implemented generator has a value

```
from itertools import chain
def checkGen(generator, doubt):
    """Decorator used to check that we have data in the generator."""
    try:
        first = next(generator)
    except StopIteration:
        raise RuntimeError("I had no value!")
    return chain([first], generator)
```

Using this decorator, you can now define your previous solution with :

```
@checkGen
def mysolutions(...):
    ....
```

Then, you can simply use it as is, for dissociating your I/O:

```
try:
    for solution in mysolutions(...):
        print(solution) #Probably needs some formatting
except RuntimeError:
    print("I found no value (or there was some error somewhere...)")
```